# Running specific tests using Espresso and Spoon

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, spoon

I am using [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) and [Spoon](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin) for my android tests. I am extremely pleased with these. My only problem is I am trying to run a specific test. I found this on the spoon site:

> gradle spoon -PspoonClassName=fully.qualified.TestCase

But I cannot get this to work. It still runs all my test. Any suggestions? 
I am running the command like so:

> gradle spoon -PStressTest=com.espresso.websocket

Where `StressTest` is my class, and `com.espresso.websocket` is my package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out: had to add this to my `build.gradle`

```
  spoon {
     if (project.hasProperty('spoonClassName')) {
         className = project.spoonClassName  
        }
    }
```

Then run tests with this:

```
 gradle spoon -PspoonClassName=com.espresso.websosket.StressTest
```